# Logitech G110 Multimedia Keys in Linux Mint 14

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, multimedia

I know that plenty of questions have been asked about multimedia keys, but I'm having trouble finding a solution for my specific problem.

I have a Logitech G110 keyboard, which (besides the macro keys) works fine in Linux; however, the multimedia keys aren't working at all in any media program. The keys are being detected by the *Keyboard Shortcuts* window but aren't doing anything in any other program. The volume wheel, mute button, mute headphones/microphone buttons, and backlighting all work fine. Only the multimedia keys are malfunctioning.

Is there anything I can do, a tool I can download, some configuration file I can change, to get these working?